# compile error in recursively go down folder structure and to delete specific files

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Actual code look on desktop and its subfolders,then delete csv,xlsm and xlsb.

But I am getting a compile error

For control variable already in use.

Any ideas what is going wrong

```
Dim FSO As Object

Sub delkillcsv()

    Dim myFiles As Object, file As Object
    Dim startFold As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    startFold = "C:\Test\Demo"

    If Right(startFold, 1) = "\" Then
        startFold = Left(startFold, Len(startFold) - 1)
    End If

    Set myFiles = FSO.GetFolder(startFold).Files

    For Each file In myFiles
        If InStr(file.Name, ".csv") Then
            Kill file.Path
        End If
    Next
    For Each file In myFiles
        If InStr(file.Name, ".xlsm") Then
            Kill file.Path
        End If
    Next
    For Each file In myFiles
        If InStr(file.Name, ".xlsb") Then
            Kill file.Path
        End If
    Next

    Call chkSubfolder(FSO.GetFolder(startFold))

End Sub

Sub chkSubfolder(fold As Object)

    Dim subfolder As Object, fileCol As Object, file As Object

    For Each subfolder In fold.Subfolders
        Set fileCol = FSO.GetFolder(subfolder.Path).Files
        For Each file In fileCol
            If InStr(file.Name, ".csv") Then
                Kill file.Path
            End If
        Next

    For Each subfolder In fold.Subfolders
        Set fileCol = FSO.GetFolder(subfolder.Path).Files
        For Each file In fileCol
            If InStr(file.Name, ".xlsm") Then
                Kill file.Path
            End If
        Next

    For Each subfolder In fold.Subfolders
        Set fileCol = FSO.GetFolder(subfolder.Path).Files
        For Each file In fileCol
            If InStr(file.Name, ".xlsb") Then
                Kill file.Path
            End If
        Next


    Call chkSubfolder(subfolder)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sub is missing two Next statements. You can reuse a For ... Next control but you have to finish the For ... Next first,

```
Sub chkSubfolder(fold As Object)

    Dim subfolder As Object, fileCol As Object, file As Object

    For Each subfolder In fold.Subfolders
        Set fileCol = FSO.GetFolder(subfolder.Path).Files
        For Each file In fileCol
            If InStr(file.Name, ".csv") Then
                Kill file.Path
            End If
        Next file 
    Next subfolder    '<~~ this was missing

    For Each subfolder In fold.Subfolders
        Set fileCol = FSO.GetFolder(subfolder.Path).Files
        For Each file In fileCol
            If InStr(file.Name, ".xlsm") Then
                Kill file.Path
            End If
        Next file 
    Next subfolder    '<~~ this was missing

    For Each subfolder In fold.Subfolders
        Set fileCol = FSO.GetFolder(subfolder.Path).Files
        For Each file In fileCol
            If InStr(file.Name, ".xlsb") Then
                Kill file.Path
            End If
        Next file 
        Call chkSubfolder(subfolder)
    Next subfolder 

End Sub
```

Labeling your Next statements and utilizing conventional indentation as I've done above reduces these errors as they become very visible.

Comment: You should be able to combine two or more of the  InStr criterias to reduce your loops.